# Use TCHAR still can't use std::cout ? cout should automatically get converted to wcout right?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I thought using `TCHAR`, and setting the character set to UNICODE in Visual Studio, maybe now I could get results in wide character ie 16 bits Unicode system, but it is not working.

This is my code:

```
#include<Windows.h> //to use windows API
#include<iostream>

int main()
{
    TCHAR a[] = TEXT("This is not ANSI anymore! Olé!"); //8bits each char
    wchar_t b[] = L"This is the Unicode Olé!"; //16 bits each char
    std::cout << a << "\n";
    std::wcout << b << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

So I thought, after defining `TCHAR`, I could make use of:

```
#ifdef UNICODE
#define std::cout std::wcout
#else
#define std::cout std::cout
#endif
```

But still, my output is in hex for `TCHAR a[]`, but why? It should use `wcout` automatically, right?

Comment: `#define std::cout std::wcout` isn't a legal macro definition and `UNICODE` will not affect `cout` or `wcout`. It simply changes whether `TCHAR` is `char` or `wchar_t`. You still need to make sure that you use the correct `cout` or `wcout` matching that.

Comment: Side note: `TCHAR` is the solution to an annoying problem from the tail end of the last millennium and the beginning of this one. Microsoft had two OS lines and needed people to write code that compiled and ran on both. Today, unless you need to support   the old Windows 9X operating systems, you should just stick to wide characters.

Comment: Why are you trying to support Windows 98?

Comment: UNICODE is the wrong define. UNICODE for WinSDK, _UNICODE for the c library.

Answer (score 4):

`std::cout` does not support `wchar_t` strings, and `std::wcout` does not support `char` strings.  So you will have to pick one or the other based on which character type `TCHAR` is using.

You were right to try to use `#define` to work around that, but you used the wrong syntax for it.

Try this instead:

```
#include <Windows.h> //to use windows API
#include <iostream>

#ifdef UNICODE
#define t_cout std::wcout
#else
#define t_cout std::cout
#endif

int main()
{
    TCHAR a[] = TEXT("Olé!");
    t_cout << a << TEXT("\n");
    // or: t_cout << a << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I expect OP only posted those defines as an example of what e thinks is done automatically by windows.h

Comment: @Spencer Why would windows.h know anything about the STL?  Hmmm, OK, maybe the OP thought otherwise.

Comment: @PaulSanders The title seems to suggest that.

Answer (score 2):

> *But still, my output is in hex for `TCHAR a[]`, but why?*

You'll need to use `_setmode` with `stdout` for a correct console output. You'll need to do it to `stdin` also if you want to read console input.

> *It should use `wcout` automatically, right?*

The macros are not correct, but if you define them correctly and assuming you enabled unicode, yes, `TCHAR` should expand t `wchar_t`, and the used output macro will be the one enabled by your `#ifdef` condition:

```
#include <Windows.h> //to use windows API
#include <iostream>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <io.h>

#ifdef UNICODE
#define tcout std::wcout //unicode enabled
#else
#define tcout std::cout
#endif

int main()
{
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_WTEXT); // enable wide char output

    TCHAR a[] = TEXT("This is not ANSI anymore! Olé!");
    tcout << a << TEXT("\n");
}
```

With `_setmode`:

[image]

Without `_setmode`:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In Windows with `UNICODE` set, TCHAR comes out to `wchar_t`.

You can't use `std::cout` with wide characters. It only ever uses `char`.   windows.h doesn't redefine cout in the way you think.

So it's as if you were outputting an array of (signed or unsigned) `short` to the stream.  The array decays to a pointer and that's probably why you see hex.

However

```
std::wcout << a << "\n";
```

should work.

Comment: *"You can't use std::cout with wide characters."* - No one is trying to. The code passes a **pointer** to a `wchar_t`. And that is well supported by `std::cout`. *"So it's as if you were outputting an array of (signed or unsigned) short to the stream."* - No, it isn't. Overload resolution selects the generic pointer specialization, and outputs the pointer value.

Comment: @IInspectable Tomato, tomahto.

Comment: @IInspectable "*The code passes a pointer to a `wchar_t`. And that is well supported by `std::cout`*" - not the way the OP wants, though. `std::cout` does not have an `operator<<` to print a `wchar_t*` string as characters, it will get handled by the `operator<<` for `void*` instead. Same with `std::wcout` with a `char*` string

Comment: And all basic_ostreams can print `const char*` c-strings, so `std::wcout` also works without `UNICODE`. So basically, use `std::wcout` for a `LPCTSTR` c-string

Comment: @Artyer But it wouldn't output a `std::basic_string<char>` , or a `string_view<char>` which is what OP should have used anyway.

Answer (score -1):

It's only possible for functions that are part of the Windows API, because the `windows.h` header file defines two functions, one each for ASCII and Unicode forms. `TCHAR` would change only for those present there.

`cout` and `wcout` are not part of the Windows API. Rather, they are part of the standard C++ `iostream` header, so they do not change based on the definition of `TCHAR`.